# Multiple Scripts all in one with breaks

Tags: shell-script, time, nohup, sleep

I’m writing a script where instead of using ‘sleep 600’ (for example), i actually want to execute another script for the same amount of time as sleep.

So basically, instead of “doing nothing” for 10 min, bash would work on something else.

Once the time is up, bash would pick up where it left off on the first script.  Then repeat until both processes are complete.

Another potential option is to do loop 1 on process 1, do loop 1 on process 2, then if the time it takes to do loop 1 is < sleep time, sleep for the remainder and continue.  In this scenario I would have to time the processes.

Any idea on how incorporate this timing element with multiple scripts ?

Comment: You don't mention any relation between the two scripts, any requirements like the one to wait for the other etc. So why to do this? Why isn't it enough to launch both scripts and let them finish as fast as they can.

Comment: The idea is to not overload the receiving server with multiple requests from script 1.  Think of it as “ask for information” (script 1), “process information for x seconds” (script 2), “wait if time elapsed < specified wait time”, “ask for more information” (script 1 again).

Comment: are those "request information" and "process information" steps related to each other in any way? What happens if there's more information to process than be deal with in the given time slots? Why not write two scripts, one for each task, and let the operating system handle the scheduling between the two processes?

Comment: looks to me as if you are trying to re-invent time sharing in bash.